# Texto gradiente android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

É possível criar um um gradiente no texto(e não no *background*) de um *textView* utilizando apenas *XML*?

Sei que utilizando *shader* é possível fazer com código([aqui](https://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/13))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer isso utilizando apenas *XML*?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link do Stack Overflow Internacional, funcionou muito bem pra mim, e não foi difícil de implementar. [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631322/set-gradient-color-for-text-in-android-studio-with-kotlin-language)

Answer (score 2):

Não parece ser possível criar `TextView` com texto com gradiente apenas usando XML. No entanto é possível conseguir este efeito através da criação de uma tela e desenho sobre ele. É necessário declarar o nosso elemento de interface do usuário customizada.

**XML**

```
<br.pacote.TextGradient
                android:id="@+id/txtVersao"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnEntrar"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="GRADIENT" />
```

**TextView Customizado**

```
public class TextGradient extends TextView {

    public TextGradient(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TextGradient(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextGradient(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {

        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, super.getTextSize(), Color.RED, Color.BLUE,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        super.getPaint().setShader(shader);
        super.setText(text.toString(), type);
    }
}
```

**Imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma, é possível utilizar o `TextGradient` no `.xml`.