# Como usar gradient em algum componente do Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Como usar o efeito de degrade em algum componente do Android? Como por exemplo a navigation bar , ou um simples `TextView`?

Comment: Você quer dizer no finado ActionBar, atual Toolbar?

Comment: Digo em qualquer componente , por exemplo um textview , quero que ele comece em uma cor e vá mudando para outra , da um certo efeito degrade

Comment: Olha essa minha resposta se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155735/35406

Comment: Ajudou sim , mas e se eu fosse fazer um gradiente na toolbar , como seria ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O XML fornece a *tag* `<gradient>` no qual é possível realizar essa façanha. Basicamente você define uma cor inicial, uma cor central (não obrigatória) e uma cor final para realizar tal efeito. Veja abaixo os seguintes atributos:

- `startColor`: cor inicial
- `centerColor`: cor central
- `endColor`: cor final
- `angle`: o angulo no qual pode ser rotacionado, no qual pode ser definido como `0`, `90`, `180`, `270`.

Existem [outros atributos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) descritos na documentação.

Então pode ser criado arquivo no diretório *drawable* por exemplo com o nome [`gradient.xml`](https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/res/drawable/gradient.html):

> drawable/gradient.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#6586F0"
            android:centerColor="#D6D6D6"
            android:endColor="#4B6CD6"
            android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Para finalizar, basta definir como background de alguma *view*, sendo um `Button`, `TextView`, `Toolbar`, `LinearLayout`, etc. Veja:

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

Exemplo de aplicação:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/thebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:text="Button Gradient!"
    />
```

Comment: @paiva a resposta foi clara ou precisa de mais algum exemplo?

Comment: Sim , obrigado amigo

Answer (score 2):

Crie um layout gradient em `res/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#faef4f"
        android:endColor="#01040a"
        android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

Atribua à propriedade background de seu componente o seu drawable

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/empresa"
            android:textColor="#070701"
            android:maxHeight="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient">*
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
        </TextView>
```